# While trying to provide user input, I am Getting ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack while trying to

Tags: python

I was trying to solve one practice problem statement in Hackerearth site. Below is my code:

```
Length = int(raw_input())
NumberOfPhotoes = int(raw_input())
Width=list()
Height=list()
for i in range(NumberOfPhotoes):
    w,h = map(int,raw_input().split())    
    Width.append(w)
    Height.append(h)
    #Height = int(raw_input())
    if (Width[i] < Length) | (Height[i] < Length):
        print "UPLOAD ANOTHER"
    elif (Width[i] == Height[i] == Length):
        print "ACCEPTED"
    else:
        print "CROP IT"   
    w = 0
    h = 0
```

When I ran the above code, after providing first set of data below error message displayed:

```
180
3
640 480
CROP IT
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:\Project_Using_Eclipse\HackerEarth_Practice\Roy_and_profile_Picture.py", line 6, in 
>       w,h = map(int,raw_input().split())
>       ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

Comment: It would be VASTLY easier to tell what's going on with your program if you included a prompt string in each `raw_input()` call, so that you can tell what you're supposed to be entering on each line.

Comment: After `CROP IT` print are you providing values(like `640 480`)? because simple enter will generate that error

Comment: Why do you need to shout at your program? `crop` is friendlier than `CROP IT`

Answer (score 0):

Getting your input, splitting it, mapping it immediately to `int` and then unpacking it to two variables might look *neat* but is incredibly fragile as any non-expected input (i.e. anything that's not two integers separated by whitespace) will break it. Your error occurs in one of such cases (I would guess you press enter after the third prompt).

Do some error handling instead:

```
input_data = raw_input().split()
if len(input_data) < 2:
    print("INVALID INPUT!")  # to stay with the uppercase
    continue  # maybe you want to run this in a loop instead?
try:
    w = int(input_data[0])
    h = int(input_data[1])
except ValueError:
    print("INVALID INPUT!")  # to stay with the uppercase
    continue  # maybe you want to run this in a loop instead?
# now you're safe to use your `w` and `h` variables
```

Comment: Completely agree and will incorporate your suggestion.